# Desktop,Music and Public folder in the Home directory gets Link (broken) (inode/symlink) on opening a pdf in the Home directory.How do I fix it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, symbolic-link, ubuntu-20.04

Yesterday I shut down my laptop and it took an exceptionally long time to shut down after lots of messages being displayed by the OS(Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS) on shutdown.

Today,when I started my laptop it started showing all the files and directories in my `Home` Directory.

I fixed that issue by referring to the below two links:

[Link 1](https://superuser.com/questions/974905/desktop-is-mirroring-home-folder-and-deleting-folders-removes-them-permanently)

[Link 2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207216/user-dirs-dirs-reset-at-start-up)

But after opening `tkt.pdf` in the `Home` directory,the links to the `Desktop,Music` and `Public` folder once again gets corrupted as shown in the below images.

[Home directory when tkt.pdf not opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u08ZM.png)

[Home directory after tkt.pdf is opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b73DG.png)

Can anyone tell me what exactly is causing this problem all of a sudden and suggest me a way to fix it?